# Connecting to Oracle11g database from Websphere message broker 6

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am trying a simple insert command from websphere message broker 6 from a compute node.
The data source name which is provided in the odbc.ini file in the message broker is specified in the node property of the compute node. And have wrote the following ESQL code.

```
SET TABLE = 'MYTABLE';
SET MYVALUE = 'TESTVALUE';

INSERT INTO Database.TABLE VALUES(MYVALUE);
```

The connection url is provided in the tnsnames.ora. The url is cluster url. Which points to 3 database instances.

When I am running the query i am getting exception that table or view does not exist in the trace.
But when i connect to db using any of the 3 direct urls, i am able to see the table.
Note: database is oracle11g

Can any one explain me what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my application was using the same DSN used by my broker. And while creating the broker, the username and password provided was pointing to different schema, which is not having the the tables for my application.

The solution was creating a new DSN, and using mqsisetdbparams to point it to the correct schema.